# Vagrant run command: Where, what and why?

Tags: vagrant

Following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-vagrant-up-and-running-in-no-time) on the Vagrant website, I was able to get a virtual machine up and running very easily, but now I'm trying to create a different virtual machine by forking a repository linked below.

The README in [this repository](https://github.com/honza/django-chef) tells me to do this:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/honza/django-chef.git
$ cd django-chef
# add yourself to the "users" array in the Vagrantfile
$ sudo echo "127.0.0.1 example.example.com" >> /etc/hosts
$ vagrant up
$ fab vagrant:honza bootstrap  # replace with your name
$ vagrant ssh    
$ run            # ME (doctordoder): This command is not found?
```

*"Then open your browser to http://example.example.com:3456."*

The difference being that the other tutorial stops at `vagrant up`, and then the website is available.

When I tried to do these extra steps with this more difficult repository, I got this **(I did these commands after I had already ran** `vagrant up` **in the django-chef directory successfuly)**: [image: My terminal pic]

**Where is this so called "run" command in vagrant? Why do I need it? And why is it unavailable to me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's not a vagrant command :) It's a custom command that's put in by the chef provisioner.

I scanned the source code of the repository and you can find a .erb template in the following folder:

```
django-chef/cookbooks/example/templates/default/bashrc.erb [line 23]
```

within this file there is a custom function defined named "run". This function will execute the "runserver" command form django ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/))

The file

```
django-chef/cookbooks/example/recipes/default.rb [line 23]
```

is responsible for updating the .bashrc file on the guest machine and that's why you can call the "run" command from inside the guest machine.

So basically you are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: I actually was able to arrive at this answer eventually (I became obsessed with this problem), but I am wondering how you were able to "scan" the repository. I'm new to them. Freaking amazingly useful, so I have to ask every time I hear of a new feature.

Comment: By "scanning" I mean look into it ;)